# Leaving feedback to a buyer using REST APIs

Tags: ebay-api

In the Trading API, it was possible to leave feedback for a buyer with either the CompleteSale or LeaveFeedback calls.
I'm building a new application from scratch and using the newer REST APIs, but was unable to find any reference to feedback in any of them. I would have assumed this would be part of the Fulfillment API, which handles orders and their fulfillment, but apparently the new version of CompleteSale (createShippingFulfillment) no longer supports leaving feedback and there's no call dedicated to leaving feedback as far as I can tell.

Is feedback no longer a thing in the new REST APIs?

Answer (score 0):

LeaveFeedback call works and is fairly simple:  tried to give code example but its not allowing me thinks I am trying to inject code :)

Use XML and PHP works fine